Troubleshooting slow write performance on hard drive
Issue
I have 4 SSDs in a RAID0 array. I notice recently that when I am doing anything while on the array mountpoint I will run into these short glitches/pauses. For example, assume I am editing a file with vim. I am typing away and nothing is showing up, then a bunch of characters will fill the line (a short freeze). Or, I am in vim and I am moving my cursor around, I will have to wait a few seconds for the cursor to catch up. Final example, I am scp'ing a file to the system, it finishes writing the file then sits at 99% for 5-10 minutes doing nothing.
mdstat Output
Personalities : [raid0]
md127 : active raid0 sdc1[2] sdd1[3] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      3750236160 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>

Mount output
/dev/md127 on /mnt/r0 type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,sunit=1024,swidth=4096,noquota)

Writing with dd
So I decided to run dd to see what my write speeds look like:
# dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 78.7336 s, 13.6 MB/s

While on a server that is not having issues (same drives, same configuration):
# dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 6.17901 s, 174 MB/s

strace Output from rclone process
Here's the end snippet attaching to an rclone process that is copying a file from a remote location to the array. I notice with all processes that hang I see a constant stream of <... futex resumed>)        = ? lines:
[pid 17120] read(8,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17118] <... fadvise64 resumed>)    = 0
[pid 17120] <... read resumed>"", 32768) = 0
[pid 17118] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17120] fadvise64(8, 14665777152, 34827, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] <... nanosleep resumed>NULL) = 0
[pid 17118] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] <... fadvise64 resumed>)    = 0
[pid 17116] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17120] close(8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17118] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] <... close resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17116] <... nanosleep resumed>NULL) = 0
[pid 17120] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17116] <... getpid resumed>)       = 17115
[pid 17118] futex(0xc000ab3148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17126] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17120] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/r0/tmp/test/foo.img",  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid 17126] futex(0xc000ab3148, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] tgkill(17115, 17120, SIGURG <unfinished ...>
[pid 17118] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] <... tgkill resumed>)       = 0
[pid 17120] <... newfstatat resumed>0xc000b222a8, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17116] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=17115, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 17120] rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17120] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/r0/tmp/test",  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] <... nanosleep resumed>NULL) = 0
[pid 17120] <... newfstatat resumed>{st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
[pid 17116] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/r0/tmp/test/foo.img", 0xc000b22448, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17120] renameat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/r0/tmp/test/foo.img.partial", AT_FDCWD, "foo.img" <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] <... nanosleep resumed>NULL) = 0
[pid 17120] <... renameat resumed>)     = 0
[pid 17116] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=20000},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "foo.img", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14665811979, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
[pid 17120] futex(0xc0000c4948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 17116] <... nanosleep resumed>NULL) = 0
[pid 17118] futex(0xc000ab3148, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17116] getpid( <unfinished ...>
[pid 17120] exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17118] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid 17120] <... exit_group resumed>)   = ?
[pid 17144] <... futex resumed>)        = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 17115] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17149] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17145] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17143] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17130] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17128] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17127] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17126] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17125] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid 17124] <... futex resumed>)        = ?

Other Troubleshooting Steps
I've done all the following troubleshooting:

Checked all drives for SMART errors: smartctl -a /dev/<device> - No errors, no attributes showing any issues (e.g., Reallocated_Sector_Ct)
Checked for any potential memory issues: cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*/ue_count and cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*/ce_count both report 0.
Checked CPU load, everything is essentially idle.
Watched iostat/iotop output to determine if something else was writing, no activity.
Checked dmesg output for any kernel errors, nothing.

Question
Is there anything missing here as far as troubleshooting goes? Is there anything more that can be done? When a drive is slow, yet is not presenting kernel errors or SMART errors, do you simply replace the drive and assume it was some sort of mechanical failure, or?? If it is not the drive, what other things beyond ECC errors, CPU usage, etc, could be involved?

you wrote about a Harddisk in the topic while in the post we speak about a ssd raid. it is for me unclear what you try or do. And if it is I. e. connected via USB there is also a chance of differences

It is an array of SSD drives connected via SATA. There's nothing USB involved in here at all.

as we speak about a server, which is it?  how is it configured?

Supermicro SYS-120H-TNR, 2x Xeon Platinum 8351N Processors, 256GB Memory (MEM-DR464MC-ER32), 1x 1TB Samsung EVO drive for the OS, 4x 4TB Samsung EVO Drives in a RAID0 array.
I'm not trying to troubleshoot my specific problem. I'm more looking for general guidelines with regards to other steps in the troubleshooting process when read/writes are slow.
